# asp.net forms with web service wont accept POST params

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, web-services

I have a Web Service in a ASP.NET web forms project, I'm trying to POST data to a method on the web service and then return a JSON object instead of the default XML.

My webservice method simplified for the example looks like this:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public DataControl.JSONMessage NavigationItemsUpdate(string description, int id, string linkText)
    {

            DataControl.JSONMessage response = new DataControl.JSONMessage();
            response.Name = "Item Update";
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Submiting the following POST via AJAX

```
 linkText=Skill+AquisitionAaAa&sequence=5&description=Learn+new+game+skills&uid=7&oper=edit&id=7
```

Works with the default content type except the response is in XML

```
 Content-Type   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

response:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <JSONMessage xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Name>Item Update</Name>
  <State>Failed</State>
  <Message0>Update</Message0>
 </JSONMessage>
```

The only way I have managed to get a JSON response is to set my AJAX call's content type to

```
  contentType: "application/json",
```

Which gets a JSON response from the Asp.Net's Web Service although it has issues reading the POST params and returns this exception

```
 {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: linkText.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

as it expects the POST to be in JSON not as a normal POST

My issue is how can I force a web service method to expect POST params but respond in JSON?

Comment: When you set contentType as json, you should post json.

Comment: I realise this, my issue is I dont know how to get a JSON response from asp.net's web service unless the content-type is set to JSON. Any suggestion on how to force a JSON response from the web service on a normal content-type instead of the XML default would be highly appreciated.